# How can I save the CurrentItem of Picker in QML?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Helo, I defined in mainView the following functions:

```
property var db: null

function openDB() {
    if(db !== null) return;

    // db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(identifier, version, description, estimated_size, callback(db))
    db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("pedometer.ubik", "0.1", "Simple example app", 100000);

    try {
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings(key TEXT UNIQUE, value TEXT)');
            var table  = tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM settings");
            // Seed the table with default values
            if (table.rows.length == 0) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO settings VALUES(?, ?)', ["Stepslength", "0.7"]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO settings VALUES(?, ?)', ["Sensivity", "5.2"]);
                console.log('Settings table added');
            };
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating table in database: " + err);
    };
}


function saveSetting(key, value) {
    openDB();
    db.transaction( function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO settings VALUES(?, ?)', [key, value]);
    });
}

function getSetting(key) {
    openDB();
    var res = "";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE key=?;', [key]);
        res = rs.rows.item(0).value;
    });
    return res;
}
```

The function saveSetting saves my Setting. The functions getSetting returns a setting value.

Now I want to use a picker to save the setting:

```
Picker {
    id: pickerStepslength
    selectedIndex: parseInt(getSetting("Stepslength")) // this will be set to 0 at the model completion

    delegate: PickerDelegate {
        Label {
            text: modelData
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var stack = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
            stack.push(i / 100.0);
        }
        model = stack;
        // selectedIndex must be set explicitly
        selectedIndex = parseInt(getSetting("Stepslength"))
    }


    onSelectedIndexChanged: {
         saveSetting("Stepslength", selectedIndex)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't saves the selectedIndex into my database.

It should restore the selectedIndex from database.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I suspect the problem is that you're storing the database connection instead of re-obtaining it each time you need to access the database.  The [LocalStorage documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html) says, "Database connections are automatically closed during Javascript garbage collection."  This makes me wonder if the  connection is closed at the end of the `openDB()` function, as it doesn't recognize that the connection is being stored in a QML property.

I would change to code so that `openDB()` calls `openDatabaseSync()` each time, and returns to the database connection to the caller, which will use it as a local variable.  This is the pattern I've always seen used.

It looks like your database initialization code is properly guarded, but there may be a better approach.  The first would be to pass a callback to `openDatabaseSync()`.  This will only be called if the database is just now created, and a database connection is passed as an argument.  Thus, the initialization code can be run inside the call back.  Another approach would be to check `db.version` after getting the connection.  On first run, this will be the empty string.  In later runs, it will be set to the value passed in `openDatabaseSync()`.  Checking this value is also useful for performing database upgrades.

As an example, you can check out [this QML file](https://github.com/rschroll/beru/blob/master/ui/LocalBooks.qml) from my project Beru.